# Django generic List View with multiple query search

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

Hello I'm working with class based views in Django and I want to create a search form for users to find their own favourite products in my app with multiple filters and excludes but I couldn't do it. my code is here if anyone can modify it to make it right please help me out :

models.py

```
from django.db.models import models
from django.core.validators import RegexValidators


class Product(models.Model):
    num=RegexValidators(r'^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    embed_id = models.CharField(max_length=15, validators=[num])
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms


class ProductSearchForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(required=False)
    embed_id = forms.CharField(required=False)
    description = forms.CharField(required=False)
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Product
from .forms import ProductSearchForm


class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    form_class = ProductSearchForm
    template_name = 'pages/product/list_products.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
       queryset = super().get_queryset()
       form = self.form_class(self.request.GET)
       if form.is_valid():
           title = form.cleaned_data.get('title')
           embed_id = form.cleaned_data.get('embed_id')
           description = form.cleaned_data.get('description')
           if title:
              queryset = queryset.filter(title__icontains=title)
           if embed_id:
              queryset = queryset.filter(embed_id__icontains=embed_id)
           if description:
              queryset = queryset.filter(description__icontains=description)
           return queryset

   def get_context_data(self, [**kwargs):
      context = super().get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      context['form'] = self.form_class(self.request.GET)
      return context
```

product_search.html

```
<form method="get" action="{% url 'product_list' %}">
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
{% if object_list %}
<ul>
{% for product in object_list %}
<li>{{ product.title }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
<p>No product found.</p>
{% endif %}
```

I know how to handle this in Function based views, but I want to create its generic.listview.

Comment: What exactly could you not do? What isn't working?

Comment: I want to retrive the data based on Users search in list view, when user search "title" or "embed_id" or anything else, He should get a results based on Database content.

Comment: I get that. Still, what about that whole process is not working? Data isn't appearing at all, isn't getting filtered correctly, ...? Without that information it is difficult to help

Comment: Sorry about bad explenation, I think It didn't work in "get_queryset()" method because when I assgin just one filter, it can handle it but when I try to handle more than one filter, It goes faile and return nothing

Comment: In this case, are you sure that there exist data that matching all the conditions? If you want to query data that match any of the conditions, you will have to use `OR` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using your code cannot run.

Here is my way:

### views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Product
from .forms import ProductSearchForm


class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    form_class = ProductSearchForm
    template_name = 'product.html'
    context_object_name = 'products'
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        form = self.form_class(self.request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            title = form.cleaned_data.get('title')
            embed_id = form.cleaned_data.get('embed_id')
            description = form.cleaned_data.get('description')
            if title:
                queryset = queryset.filter(title__icontains=title)
            if embed_id:
                queryset = queryset.filter(embed_id__icontains=embed_id)
            if description:
                queryset = queryset.filter(description__icontains=description)
        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.form_class(self.request.GET)
        return context
```

## all data

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lcNU.png)

## search data

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbYuL.png)

Comment: Why is there def get_context_data(self, [**kwargs):?

Comment: when you want to send multiple data into template AND you want to control them seprately, You need to change the "get_context_data()" method.